# How to stop this function at the given point?

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, execution

```js
var counter;
var count = 0;
//var booli = new Boolean("false");

window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('banana')
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let y = x[i];
    console.log(y);
    x[i].onmousedown = debounce(function() {
      //if(booli)
      //{
      start(y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
      //};
    }, 550);
  };
}

function debounce(a, b) {
  return function() {
    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      a();
    }, b);
  };
}

function start(clicked_className, cha) {
  counter = setInterval(function() {
    add(clicked_className, cha);
    count++;
  }, 90);
}

function end() {
  //booli=false;
  clearInterval(counter);
}

function add(clicked_className, cha) {
  window.document.numeri.outpu.value =
    window.document.numeri.outpu.value + cha;
}
```

```css
#put {
  width: 700px;
  height: 18px;
  font-size=14pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmouseup="end()">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form name="numeri">
    <input type="text" id="put" name="outpu">
    <input type="button" id="apple" class="banana" value="  1  " onmouseleave="end()">
    <input type="button" id="ada" class="banana" value="  2  " onmouseleave="end()">
    <input type="button" id="aded" class="banana" value=" 3  " onmouseleave="end()">

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Hey guys!
Goal: stop the function that writes numbers before it starts writing numbers
without the commented things the program works, but its not stopping, so i wanted to stop it from executing the function that writes numbers with a boolean.
It has to stop when leaving the button
Why does it not work?
And what are the alternatives?

Comment: In what way does the code fail?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  This is probably a good time to open your browser's debugging tools and use the development console and script debugger.

Comment: What's wrong with using the boolean variable? BTW, `new Boolean("false")` should just be `false`.

Comment: Could you use a `break` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a couple of issues.  The 550ms delay on the timeout is causing the onmouseleave to fire before the code in debounce.  Also your booli was being set in the wrong spot and was never being reset to true.

```js
  let counter;
  let count = 0;
  let booli = false;

  window.onload = function() {
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('banana')
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      let y = x[i];
      console.log(y);
      x[i].onmousedown = debounce(function() {          
        start(y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));          
      }, 1);//550
    }
  }

  function debounce(a, b) {
    return function() {
      let timer;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      booli = true;
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if(booli)
        {
          a();
        }
        else
        {
          clearInterval(counter);
        }
      }, b);
    };
  }

  function start(clicked_className, cha) {
    counter = setInterval(function() {
      add(clicked_className, cha);
      count++;
    }, 90);
  }

  function end() {
    booli = false;
    clearInterval(counter);
  }

  function add(clicked_className, cha) {
    window.document.numeri.outpu.value =
      window.document.numeri.outpu.value + cha;
  }
```

```css
#put{
width = 700px;
height: 18px;
font-size=14pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmouseup="end()">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form name="numeri">
    <input type="text" id="put" name="outpu" style { width = 700px; height: 18px; font-size=14pt; }>
    <input type="button" id="apple" class="banana" value="  1  " onmouseleave="end()">
    <input type="button" id="ada" class="banana" value="  2  " onmouseleave="end()">
    <input type="button" id="aded" class="banana" value=" 3  " onmouseleave="end()">

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On why it doesn't work:

You have an issue with the way your events are behaving on your `<input type="button">`s.
For some reason, when you click a button, the `onMouseLeave` event is triggering, which is running `end()`. This, in turn, is setting `booli` to `false`, which is why it felt like something was wrong with your boolean.
You're also never setting `booli` to be true anywhere in the code you shared.

`booli` gets set to false before `onMouseDown` and `start()` never gets called.

I set `booli` as true in your declaration and threw a couple log statements into your code to show what I mean:

```js
var counter;
var count = 0;
var booli = true;
console.log("booli=", booli);

window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('banana')
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let y = x[i];
    x[i].onmousedown = debounce(function() {
      console.log("onMouseDown, booli is", booli);
      if(booli) {
        start(y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
      }
    }, 550);
  };
}

function debounce(a, b) {
  return function() {
    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      a();
    }, b);
  };
}

function start(clicked_className, cha) {
  counter = setInterval(function() {
    add(clicked_className, cha);
    count++;
  }, 90);
}

function end() {
  console.log("onMouseLeave, setting booli=false");
  booli=false;
  clearInterval(counter);
}

function add(clicked_className, cha) {
  window.document.numeri.outpu.value =
    window.document.numeri.outpu.value + cha;
}
```

```css
#put {
  width: 700px;
  height: 18px;
  font-size=14pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmouseup="end()">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form name="numeri">
    <input type="text" id="put" name="outpu">
    <input type="button" id="apple" class="banana" value="  1  " onmouseleave="end()">
    <input type="button" id="ada" class="banana" value="  2  " onmouseleave="end()">
    <input type="button" id="aded" class="banana" value=" 3  " onmouseleave="end()">

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```